Add a formula within the field of a filter function
I would like to add a formula inside the field of a filter. My formula aims to filter the cells that are including an element from a list stored in another cell. The list is {test1,test2,test3}.
I've tried two versions of my formula
=REGEXMATCH(A1,""""&A2&"""")
=IF(COUNTIF(BYCOL(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"{",""),"}",""),CHAR(34)&";"&CHAR(34)),lambda(x,A2=x)),TRUE),TRUE,FALSE)

They are working stand alone but not in the field. When I'm trying to input them, they are disappearing and nothing is filtered.
Thanks for your help


Could you clarify the result you're expecting? The input box on the filter is designed for wildcard searches, not for data processing.

I'm expecting to keep only lines 8,9,10,12 where there is one of the tree elements stored in A1 cell (i.e. test1, test2 or test3)

You have to choose the 'Filter by condition' (Filtrer par condition) option, not the 'Filter by value'.

Your REGEXMATCH formula should work; if you want an even more precise regular expression, you can try this one out:
=REGEXMATCH($A$1, "^.*(?:{|;)"&CHAR(34)&"(?i)"&A8&CHAR(34)&"(?:}|;).*$")

It is case-insensitive - if you want it to be case sensitive, remove the &"(?i)" part - and would allow you to drop the quote marks around each item in your list if you wish, by removing the two &CHAR(34).
EDIT: Previously, I had suggested the following formulae, which should be avoided, since they would also match parts of words and not only whole words:
=FIND(A8, $A$1)>0 ;
or, if you don't want it to be case-sensitive: =SEARCH(A8, $A$1)>0.

Indeed it's better to use "Filter by condition" but the formula that you proposed is not working. Nothing is filtered

I added a screenshot to avoid any possible confusion about where you should be typing the formula.

Hello @user27425627 thanks for your answer. It's not working as expected. There is now a filter but the REGEXMATH formula keeps only the first line that match the criterion but all the other lines that could bekept are not displayed. It's like if the filter stops at the first occurence.
Also, I don't understand how  &"(?i)" part works?
Thanks for your help

(?i) is a modifier that uses the i flag to make the match case-insensitive for everything that comes next - so that tEsT1 would match test1, for instance. See https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax and ctrl+F "(?flags)".

ok thanks for the explanation. Any idea why REGEXMATCH holds only one occurence? Is there an alternative way to proceed or make a correction to the formula please?
